# Программа не определяет тип данных

Tags: c++, функции, перегрузка-функций

Создал перегруженную функцию с типами данных `char`, `long`, `double`.Visual Studio не может определить разницу между `char` и `long` и подчеркивает их,как исправить это?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
char avg(char* x, char* y) {
    return (*x * *y) / 2;
}
double avg(double x, double y) {
    return (x * y) / 2;
}
long avg(long x, long y) {
    return (x * y) / 2;
}
int main()
{
    cout << avg(7,6) << endl; // тут лонг
    cout << avg(2.0, 10.0) << endl;
    cout<<avg(2,3)<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Литералы 7 и 6 имеют тип `int`, и могут быть сконвертированы как в `long`, так и в `double`.

Comment: @VladD, привет! Как дела?

Comment: @avp: Ничего вроде, карантин и home-office, появилось свободное время :)

Comment: @VladD, OK, рад видеть вас снова

Comment: @avp: Ну я ненадолго, так просто мимо крокожу.

Answer (score 3):

В вызовах `avg(7, 6)` и `avg(2, 3)` Вы передаете аргументы типа `int`, которые могут быть преобразованы и в `long` и в `double`. Компилятор не может определиться и генерирует ошибку. Передавайте аргументы типа `long` просто добавив суффикс `L`:

```
cout << avg(7L ,6L) << endl;
cout << avg(2.0, 10.0) << endl;
cout << avg(2L, 3L) << endl;
```

Вы говорите, что не может определить разницу между `char` и `long`. У Вас нет ни одной функции, которая принимает аргументы типа `char`. Есть функция, которая принимает указатели на `char`, но в коде такая нигде не вызывается.